# Chrome API retrieving most recently downloaded file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a function in the Chrome API that gets the most recently downloaded file?

My goal is to grab this file, copy it, and save it to a different location since in Chrome you cannot change the default download directory for specific file types/websites:
[How to set download location via chrome api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653361/how-to-set-download-location-via-chrome-api)

Is this idea feasible?

Answer (score 1):

The [`chrome.downloads` API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads.html) just became stable with Chrome 31. It allows you to deal with all download interactions, like getting the filename and the MIME type. I'm not sure if and how you can copy and move files on the user's system by a Chrome extension.

For your goal you could use the [`onDeterminingFilename`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads.html#event-onDeterminingFilename) function and alter the filename to contain subdirectories, like putting all `.jpg` files into `Downloads/images/`.

Comment: Trying this now Max. Thanks.

Comment: Max, this works, but I can only write inside of the Downloads folder. Is there anyway to specify a folder outside of your default downloads folder? For example, I'm trying to save these files to my temp folder. I tried setting the filename = "C:\Users\myuser\Local\appdata\temp\myfile.xml" but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Laterade The documentation explicitly states that "Absolute paths, empty paths, and paths containing back-references will cause an error.". So I guess your out of luck. You could try to use a symlink and link your temp-directory as sub-folder into downloads. I am not sure if this works, though.