# Programmatically set Chrome download location in Google Drive

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-apps

In Google Admin console, it is possible to set Chromebooks to forcibly download files to Google Drive, however it seems impossible to manage the default folder.

Is there any Google API that supports setting Chrome default download location in Google Drive?

Basically we would like to change this on our school fleet, at the beginning of the school year, depending on the students accounts or OU...
Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653361/how-to-set-download-location-via-chrome-api), who knows, things might have changed?

Comment: Since you mention a school fleet - you should be able to set this using the [Download​Directory](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=DownloadDirectory) and [DefaultDownloadDirectory](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=DefaultDownloadDirectory) Chrome policies.

Comment: I don't think you can do this through normal conventions.  It's a huge security risks as it would allow anyone to save a file anywhere on your machine.
@PetrSrníček answer appears to be the best way as a GPO or some global setting.

Comment: @PetrSrníček the setting you have mentioned applies to local storage. In Admin Console, you can force users to download only to Google Drive, but apparently there's no way to specify where

Comment: @Riccardo So are you asking how to set a specific download location in Google Drive? If so, you should mention that in your question because it is not clear from your current question at all.

Comment: You are right. I have edited the post. Thank you